# GCP support page not allowing to raise issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have subscribed the gold support package on the GCP project for the support. However if I assign any user with just project owner role, we are not able to raise issue with error below, however I have logged in to G-Suite gmail account only.

You need permission to access the Google Cloud Support Center.
Please make sure you are signed in with the Google or G Suite account associated with the Google Cloud product you are inquiring about.
You are signed in as abc@abc.com

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/#how_to_sign_up_for_a_support_package):

> "By default, access to the support center is only granted to the users
>   that are project owners at the time of signing up for a support
>   package"

If access was not granted it can be done afterwards. The initial users should then grant access to other users.
Adding a member to the project with the project owner role does not mean that they will be authorized to submit support requests. If you want to add additional users to interact with support, you can follow the next steps:

1. In the [Google Cloud Support Center](https://enterprise.google.com/supportcenter) click on "User Management" which is at the top right hand corner of the screen.
2. A pane will appear that will show which users within your organisation are allowed to interact with support.
3. You can add a new user by clicking on "New User" and adding the user’s email. The user must have a valid Google Account and his address must be in your organization’s domain.
4. Select a profile and role for the user.

You can find further information and instructions on the [public documentation](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/1041916?hl=en).